# Trigger SQL Server insertar registro si se actualiza determinado campo

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger, insert

Buenas tardes compañeros tengo este trigger para insertar un registro pero solo si el campo teststatus cambia, pero aunque sean otros los campos que se actualicen me sigue insertando el registro alguien sabe porque

```
create trigger trTestStatusInsertarAct on test
    after update
    as
    begin
        IF UPDATE (TestStatus)
        begin
            insert into estadoproceso (ID ,proceso , TestStatus ,Engineer,FirstDate)
            select ID ,proceso , TestStatus ,Engineer,GETDATE()
            from inserted
        end
    end
```

Comment: No veo nada malo en este trigger. La única posibilidad que ocurra lo que dices, imagino podría se otro trigger que este actualizando específicamente ese campo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Creamos 2 tablas de prueba
create table Prueba (Id tinyint identity, Texto varchar(20), TestStatus char(1))
create table PruebaDestino (Id tinyint, Texto varchar(20), TestStatus char(1), Fecha date)

--Insertamos valores de prueba
insert into Prueba (Texto, TestStatus) 
values ('Texto 1', 'A'), ('Texto 2', 'A'), ('Texto 3', 'A'), ('Texto 4', 'A'), ('Texto 5', 'A')


alter trigger trTestStatusInsertarAct on Prueba
after update
as
begin
    declare @TestStatus char(1),
            @Id TinyInt,
            @Texto varchar(20)

    if update (TestStatus)
    insert into PruebaDestino (Id, Texto, TestStatus, Fecha)
        select i.Id, i.Texto, i.TestStatus, Getdate()
        from inserted i  
        inner join Prueba p
          on p.id = i.id
end


--Pruebas de actualizaciones
update Prueba
set TestStatus = 'x'
where Id = 5

update Prueba
set Texto = 'Texto 5'
where Id = 5

--Validaciones
select *
from PruebaDestino
```

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa valida podría ser

```
CREATE TRIGGER trTestStatusInsertarAct ON test
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN

        INSERT  INTO estadoproceso
                ( ID ,
                  proceso ,
                  TestStatus ,
                  Engineer ,
                  FirstDate
                )
                SELECT  ID ,
                        proceso ,
                        TestStatus ,
                        Engineer ,
                        GETDATE()
        SELECT  i.*
        FROM    inserted i
                INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.id = i.id
                                        AND d.TestStatus != i.TestStatus 

/*Si test status la subconsulta no trae nada, no insera*/

    END
```